# Can I create a more interactive relationship class for interaction between features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, relationship-class

Is it possible to be able to click on a point and see interacting tables? An example that I found on Google is this flight route map? http://www.ryanair.com/en/cheap-flight-destinations/

Edit: I am using ArcMap 10.2. I have two feature classes of which I am wondering if I could create an interactive relationship.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to clarify the significance of the ArcGIS tag on your question when there is no other mention of that platform, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo Apologies - I've updated the question. Is there any other information that would be useful?

Comment: You can do it, but I am pretty sure it would be a custom thing.  Do you have any experience dealing with ArcObjects (if you're wanting to view this in ArcMap) or ESRI/OpenLayers JS API (if you're putting it on a website)?

Comment: @Branco Interesting. However I've little experience with either.

Comment: @user28849 If you are looking to highlight related features like the RyanAir example, you'll need to monitor the click event.  Depending on you want to view this (in ArcMap or a webpage) it would determine how you go about it.  I think a webpage is easier, but I am more familiar with JS APIs more so than ArcObjects.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out setting up a relationship class between the two feature classes. You would need to make sure both feature classes are inside the same geodatabase.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_creating_and_maintaining_relationship_classes/004t00000006000000/

This would allow you to relate one feature class to another using a common key field. When you identify or nagivate the data, you would be able to see how they are related.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've worked quite a bit with relationship classes and I've found that while they technically achieve what I want, it is  static and not interactive and dynamic enough.

Comment: Oh no problem, it was worth a shot eh? I'm not sure how to go about it then without some programming.